# Should I open() and close() my SQL database constantly or leave it open?

Tags: android, sql, database, database-connection

I am creating an app that uses an SQL database for storing data.  The way the app is designed it will be updated every 3 minutes or so with new data depending on user actions while the app is running.

In the tutorials I have seen, they recommend that you close the database after changing it (it is an "expensive" in terms of resources).

Is it better to leave it open for the duration of my App since it is being updated on a fairly frequent basis or should I run the close() method immediately after every change?

I guess my worry is that opening it and closing it constantly will draw more resources than it would to leave it open the entire time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to leave a connection open once -- I used it to stuff a repeater or something -- can't remember now.

Later in the program, I had another need to use the connection -- I think I had it so that when a user clicked a parent item in the repeater, a detail div would pop-up with more information for that item.  This generated an error -- something to the effect of 'cannot open() on an open connection'.

I think the error might have been avoidable another way (like checking to see if the connection I was trying to open was already open), but as I thought about it, I realized I'd have to make that a standard practice throughout my app, and that seemed like too much work, so I just made it a standard practice to always close my connections after each use.

Connections stay in a connection pool -- I'm no whiz on that -- but if was curious about performance, I guess I'd keep that in mind, in terms of what it costs to open a connection multiple times -- whatever your situation is requiring anyway.

Another thought is that your DB admin may be able to force-close all open connections, or the db may close for some other reason.  If you're not the dba, you might give a thought to risk/benefit of depending on something that you don't have long-term control over like keeping the connection open.

Comment: DBA? Are we still talking about Android?

Comment: DataBase Administrator

Answer (score 3):

Three minutes is eternity on todays processors, even phone processors.  I would close it and open it each time.  It is better than possibly leaving handles hanging out in 'the ether'.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have several DB operations to do back to back in a single thread.  I'd keep the DB open to do those actions.  However close the DB after doing a chunk of work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to this question also depends on what type of application is accessing the database.

**If you re-query the database a lot**
In this case you can keep the database open.

**Are there any other applications accessing the same database?**
If there is a risk for concurrency or blocking issues, it might be wise to close the database after finished reading/writing from/to it.

Have a look onthe following url

[When to close db connection on android? Every time after your operation finished or after your app exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842112/when-to-close-db-connection-on-android-every-time-after-your-operation-finished)

Thanks Deepak

Answer (score 1):

if you ask me by everything i have read so far about android and in general it is better to close it right after you make the modifications.

What i find its best to do when you can is actually make and register a content provider.
It has its prices but i believe you gain a lot more than you pay. 
You can do pretty much everything with a content provider and the notepad example on the android portal is great for learning how to implement it. it takes care of db synchronization and opening/closing it. so maybe look into that.

Comment: have a look at the notepad tutorial and then follow it to the notepad project in examples. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: it's a bit different than the sqlite helper implementation (as an adapter or just a simple database which you will directly access through methods). i believe a content provider is a really really nice solution. after doing a lot of projects with databases and having issues with concurrency, not closing databases or running into closed databases etc etc etc to using different design patterns to solve these issues i still found that a content provider is the best solution and it worked perfectly so far for all the apps i have made. despite it having a bit larger overhead.