# data Isolation with services and Singleton SQliteOpenHelper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have implemented the SQliteOpenHelper with a Singleton pattern and it works fine till now. But consider the below sequence :

- A fragment starts a transaction to updating records
- A service gets triggered that reads the updated data
- Transaction fails for some reason and gets rolled back

The service would have processed uncommitted data that got rolled back later. So it seems that a singleton pattern coupled with a service causes problems with data isolation. Yet i have read numerous posts recommending a singleton. How does one handle this scenario when using a singleton?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private static MyApplication instance;
    public MyApplication(){
        instance = this;
    }
    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
    }
}

public class LocalDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LocalDBHelper";

    private static LocalDBHelper instance = null;
    /*private constructor to avoid direct instantiation by other classes*/
    private LocalDBHelper(){
        super(MyApplication.getContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    /*synchronized method to ensure only 1 instance of LocalDBHelper exists*/
    public static synchronized LocalDBHelper getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new LocalDBHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Usage with transactions :**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = LocalDBHelper.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
try{
....
...
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: you should check this out : http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/concurrent-database-access

Comment: @user2247689 thanks i have read that same article on 3 different sites :) But it does not deal with transactions or isolation, so is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the question properly. Dealing with services are kinda tricky especially when they have to be concurrent. Basically I guess you would have to use 'Messages'? see this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase` maintains a pool of active connections that are acquired by thread-local database sessions` - multiple threads can never acquire the same connection.

Comment: @corsair992 brilliant! you are absolutely right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A service runs on the main thread. It does not have it's own thread. It will execute only after the main thread has finished it's work. So there is no risk of a service starting when a transaction is running in an activity/fragment.
2. Two threads cannot access the same `SQliteDatabase` connection. The system is designed to allow every thread access to a unique connection from the pool. If there are no connections available, the other thread(s) will wait for one. If it has to wait long enough, you will see a logcat warning similar to what i see on my phone below. So a singleton pattern complements the SQLite's thread safety.

   `W/SQLiteConnectionPool(12695): The connection pool for database 'xyz' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 6386 (AsyncTask #2) with flags 0x1 for 4.0 seconds.
   W/SQLiteConnectionPool(12695): Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available.`
3. As a consequence of #2, there is no possible way to read uncommitted data by another thread if you use a singleton. Even if you don't use a singleton, SQLite by default provides data isolation between connections. See https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html.

**Conclusion :** The only way to read uncommitted data with a singleton is if you are on the same thread and before the transaction has ended.

Comment: Note that while the connection pool is currently set to a maximum of one if write-ahead logging is not enabled, that is not actually necessary and might be changed in the future. However, each thread will use a different session and acquire a unique connection from the pool. SQLite would of course still implement it's own locking and concurrency model.

Comment: thanks @corsair992. I confused an SQLiteDatabase instance with a connection instance. i have edited #2 to reflect your comment.