# How and when close sqlite database in application with lot of activities and services

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I read lot of about this topic but no solution can be used in my application.
Suppose there are few services and lot of activities that need to access db.
Of course only one activity is active. But in the worst scenario there is one activity and two services running background accessing db.

So when I close db from activity's onResume - service accessing db would throw exception.
And same is when I close db from service's onDestroy and there is opened cursor in activity.

I hold some kind of DBManager in my application object as singleton. I init DBManager in Application.onCreate. But there is no place to close db without risking that another Service  and activity is accesing this.

So now I never close DB - are there any consequencies doing that?
Is there same simple(or not too complicated) solution to close DB?

here are my applications in market

[russian version](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.rferl.ru)

[english version](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.rferl.en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do the same, I use a singleton database object and never close it until my application is destroyed. I didn't notice any issues so far. A more detailed answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842251/448625

Answer (score 4):

You should try using [`ContentProviders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), the Android system will then handle creating/opening/closing the database as it needs to.

Comment: But provider is the way for sharing data between applications. If I do not share data it would add a lot of complexity to application for such a little reward.

Comment: While this is true about the sharing of data; I wouldn't say it's a reason not to use a ContentProvider!

Comment: I think that architecture should be as simple as possible. If there is    no need to share data I would not suggest content provider. But good to know about it. Maybe I will use it in another application. Thanks.