# unable to debug

Tags: android, sqlite

I am unable to debug. Not able to find where to close the db.

My db helper class::

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "aviva.db";    
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_MY_DETAILS = "my_details";  
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION = "additional_information";  

      OpenHelper openHelper ;

      private Context context;  
        private SQLiteDatabase db;  

    private SQLiteStatement insertStmtMyDetails,insertStmtAdditionalInfo;
    private static final String INSERT_MY_DETAILS = "insert into " 
      + TABLE_NAME_MY_DETAILS + "(policy_number,policy_exp_date,last_name,first_name,DOB,emergency_contact) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   private static final String INSERT_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION = "insert into "
          + TABLE_NAME_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION + "(claimant_location,loss_date,claimant_description,image1,image2) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

      public DataHelper(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
       this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.insertStmtMyDetails = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT_MY_DETAILS);
      this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo=this.db.compileStatement(INSERT_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION); 
        openHelper.close();  
     }

     public void Close(){
       db.close();
       openHelper=null;
     }

      public long insertMyDetails(String policy_number,String policy_exp_date,String last_name,String first_name,String DOB,String emergency_contact) {  
       this.insertStmtMyDetails.bindString(1, policy_number);  
        this.insertStmtMyDetails.bindString(2, policy_exp_date);
        this.insertStmtMyDetails.bindString(3, last_name);
       this.insertStmtMyDetails.bindString(4, first_name);
       this.insertStmtMyDetails.bindString(5, DOB);
       this.insertStmtMyDetails.bindString(6, emergency_contact);   
       System.out.println("data inserted");
       return this.insertStmtMyDetails.executeInsert();
    }  

     public long insertAdditionalInfo(String claimant_location,String loss_date,String claimant_description,String image1,String image2 ){
           this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo.bindString(1, claimant_location);
           this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo.bindString(2, loss_date);
           this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo.bindString(3, claimant_description);
           this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo.bindString(4, image1);
           this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo.bindString(5, image2);
           System.out.println("data inserted");
           return this.insertStmtAdditionalInfo.executeInsert();
        }

     public void deleteAll() {
       this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME_MY_DETAILS, null, null);
       this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION, null, null);
    }
 private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      OpenHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_MY_DETAILS + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, policy_number TEXT,policy_exp_date TEXT,last_name TEXT,first_name TEXT,DOB TEXT,emergency_contact TEXT)");
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, claimant_location TEXT,loss_date TEXT,claimant_description TEXT,image1 TEXT,image2 TEXT)");
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_MY_DETAILS);
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION);
         onCreate(db);
      }
   }
}
```

log:

```
 12-21 10:17:29.916: ERROR/Database(893): java.lang.IllegalStateException: mPrograms   size 2
 12-21 10:17:29.916: ERROR/Database(893):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1669)  
 12-21 10:17:29.916: ERROR/Database(893):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)  
 12-21 10:17:29.916: ERROR/Database(893): Caused by:       java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/com.test.aviva.insurance/databases/aviva.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed  
 12-21 10:17:29.916: ERROR/Database(893):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1695)  
 .....
 12-21 10:17:29.985: ERROR/Database(893): Leak found  
 12-21 10:17:29.985: ERROR/Database(893): Caused by:      java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/com.test.aviva.insurance/databases/aviva.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed  
...  
 12-21 10:17:29.985: ERROR/Database(893):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1695)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try using [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Comment: Have you it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Its is good practice to open the database before executing query to database and close the database after execution of query.

Also refer [When to close db connection on android? Every time after your operation finished or after your app exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842112/when-to-close-db-connection-on-android-every-time-after-your-operation-finished)