# Clarifying When to Open and Close a DataSource

Tags: android, database

Ive done a lot of Googlig on this topic and I'm confused as to best practice.

Initially I had:

A) Created a DataBase object in my main class header area and then just passed it to functions as needed. I then later read that a DataBase should be opened and closed each time before use.

so then I:

B) went to each function (passing Context) which uses a SQL command and created a new DataBase object, created a filled cursor via SQL, and then closed the Database before returning. However, I then later read that it's expensive to do this.

now i'm thinking that:

C) I should create a new Database object in each subclass that uses one, and open and close it as needed.

Im sorry for the noob and seemingly design question (delete it if it's out of scope of StackOverflow), however, I truly am confused of how this should be handled to avoid errors, and how Google wants us to do it.

Regards

Comment: check it may help http://androidituts.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) recommend using an [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which caches the database object. From the `SQLiteOpenHelper` reference:

> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this
>   method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to
>   call `close()` when you no longer need the database.)

So, I'd go for a singleton carrying an instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so you can access it from anywhere. Then get the database where you need it, and close it on exit points of your application (if any). That way you only open a database if required, but can re-use the same connection for other tasks as well.

If you do only need the database for single tasks and/or there are other Applications accessing the same database, you may consider closing it directly after your database-tasks are done; there is a discussion about closing [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842112/when-to-close-db-connection-on-android-every-time-after-your-operation-finished).